# Disable Reset or Refresh PC in Windows 8

Tags: windows, 64-bit

I wish to disable the ability of a user to refresh or reset the PC, it should only be an admin right.

How to go about this ?

Comment: @harrymc appears to have figured out what you're actually asking. Could someone who understands edit the question so it makes sense? As entered, the question is just asking to block reset which is what the accepted answer says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the UAC slider to top position. This disables both entries in the new fullscreen control panel. UAC apps can't run elevated and so this workaround disables both features..

Comment: Okay but you can access Advanced Startup, and can refresh/reset PC from there.

Comment: sure, you still need admin rights

Comment: No, I have found even a guest can access Advanced Startup as @user197008 has said.

Answer (score 5):

I understand that the only problem left with the accepted answer is that of blocking Advanced Startup Options.

Getting to Advanced Startup Options can be done by various means:

1. Holding F8 key before Windows starts.
2. From any Power icon, either hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click on Restart.
3. From the charms bar (or <kbd>Win</kbd>+ I), click Settings / Change PC settings / Update and recovery / Recovery/ Advanced startup / Restart now.
4. Use the command `shutdown /r /o`
5. Boot from Windows 8 installation media.

From these methods, method 4 can be blocked by UAC and method 5 is unblockable.
The rest can be more or less blocked as follows.

**Holding F8 key before Windows starts**

At this point login wasn't yet done and no user account exists and so everything is permitted, as one has in effect logged-in as Administrator.

Disabling F8 is done by editing the Boot Configuration Data (BCD) information
from the Windows Command Prompt:

1. Press the <kbd>Win</kbd> key and type `cmd` in the search box, then hold
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to launch the Command Prompt with administrator privileges.
2. Type the following command into the Command Prompt:
   `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} displaybootmenu no`
   This turns off the Advanced Boot Options menu completely so pressing F8 doesn’t do anything.
3. To enable F8 again, type the following into Command Prompt:
   `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} displaybootmenu yes`

However, a knowledgeable user can still force it via :

- The `Safe Boot` option from MsConfig (needs Administrator privilege).
- This won't work for a multiboot system.
- The boot menu will still show after an improper startup/shutdown or sudden loss of power etc.

**Disable Access to Control Panel and PC settings**

To enable or disable access to the Control Panel, PC settings, and all settings in them for all or specific users in Windows 8.

When disabled, this setting prevents from starting `Control.exe` and `SystemSettings.exe`, which are the program files for Control Panel and PC settings. As a result, users cannot start Control Panel or PC settings, or run any of their items in them from any other location as well.

You must be signed in as an administrator, as
this requires using `regedit` to do some registry work. At the key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`
create a DWORD item named `NoControlPanel`, whose value is
0 to enable Control Panel/PC settings, 1 = to disable Control Panel/PC settings.

This can also be achieved via the `Local Group Policy Editor` for
[all users](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3652-local-group-policy-editor-open.html), [specific users or groups](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/151415-group-policy-apply-specific-user-group.html), or [all users except administrators](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/101869-local-group-policies-apply-all-users-except-administrators.html).
Expand User Configuration, Administrative Templates, and Control Panel,
then modify the setting for `Prohibit access to Control Panel and PC settings`.

**Remove "Power Options" Button from Start Screen**

This is done in the registry at
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell`.
Create a new sub-key named `Launcher` under ImmersiveShell key so the final key path would be:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\Launcher`.
Now in right-side pane, create a new DWORD item named
`Launcher_ShowPowerButtonOnStartScreen` and keep its value as 0.
Finally log off or restart Windows Explorer.

For more information:

[How To Access Advanced Startup Options in Windows 8 or 8.1](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/open-advanced-startup-options-windows-8.htm)
[How to Enable or Disable Access to Control Panel and PC settings in Windows 8 and 8.1](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/25294-control-panel-pc-settings-enable-disable-access.html)
[How to Add or Remove “Power Options” Button from Start Screen in Windows 8.1](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-add-or-remove-power-options-button-from-start-screen-in-windows-8-1/)

Comment: "Advanced Startup" can be accessed through Windows, F8 is not necessary. This is what needs to be disabled.

Comment: I added above some more ways to block it.

Comment: Note the Group Policy is only available with Windows 8 Pro.

Comment: "The boot menu will still show after an improper startup/shutdown or sudden loss of power etc." This can be prevented by running the following command: `bcdedit /set {current} bootstatuspolicy ignoreallfailures`

Answer (score -2):

Prevent users from shutting down or restarting Windows computer:
http://www.thewindowsclub.com/prevent-users-shutting-down-restarting-windows-computer
This is the only thing you can do.

Comment: Note this only works with Windows 8 Pro.

Comment: Question is to prevent non-admin users from resetting the PC (as in factory reset), not restart the PC.